# UIButton not clickable when implemented from a class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2

I have a class `ManageCell`, which stores the frames, set the text of labels, etc... Which are the sub-views of an UIView `CellView` which is in the `ViewController`.

> ManageCell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class ManageCell {
    var name: UILabel
    var viewBelowButton: UIView
    var deleteButton: UIButton
    init (name: String) {
        self.name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,15,250,40)
        self.name.text = name
        self.name.sizeToFit()
        self.viewBelowButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.width, 0, 70, 70)
        //set outside the visible area so that it can be animated in.
        self.viewBelowButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,70,70))
        self.deleteButton.addTarget(ViewController.self, action: "deleteButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.deleteButton.setTitle("delete", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

> ViewController:

```
var cellView: [UIView] = []
var manageCells: [ManageCell] = []
...
//fill the manageCells array
func setSubViews () {
    for (index, cell) in manageCells.enumerate() {
        cellView.append(UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, originY, view.bounds.width, 70)
        cellView[index].addSubview(cell.name)
        cellView[index].addSubview(cell.viewBelowButton)
        cell.viewBelowButton.addSubview(cell.deleteButton)
    }
}
func editing () {
    var frame = CGRectMake(view.bound.width - 70, 0, 0, 70)
    for cell in cells {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
            cell.viewBelowButton.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
func deleteButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("button pressed")
}
```

> User Interaction is enabled on both `cellView[index]`, `viewBelowButton` and `deleteButton`.

The problem I'm facing is that the `deleteButton` **does not respond to touches**. The `deleteButtonPressed:` function is not being called.

code: https://github.com/an23lm/swift-stuff

*I'm not sure if this is good practice, any suggestions are welcome.*

Comment: Sounds like the button is outside the frame of one of its superviews. Try setting `clipsToBounds` to `true` for all of the involved views. If I am correct, you will no longer be able to see the button (or at least part of it).

Comment: Why don't you do addTarget when you are adding the button in your ViewController class? That way you will have the selector in the same class. Also check the frame as Aaron rightly suggested.

Comment: @GurtejSingh Good point. That's another problem, although the button tap isn't even registering, or the OP would get a crash.

Comment: @AaronBrager Agreed! But I'm suspecting the problem is at ViewController.self. That's not an instance I think.

Comment: @GurtejSingh, I moved the `addTarget` to `ViewController`, now it is `cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: "self.deleteButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`, and still nothing. Yes, you're right about the crash, it's weird that I don't have a crash. @AaronBrager, I did move `viewBelowButton` into the frame of the screen and removed the animation (to make sure that `deleteButton` is initialized with all super-views right below it) , and used `clipToBounds`, yet no change.

Comment: @an23lm added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's not called, `ViewController.self` is a class type, not your View Controller. And if even it was, it's not a good practice. You should use a delegate pattern here with some parameter to be returned back, so you will distinguish which cell delete button was pressed.

Example on your code:

```
protocol ManageCellDelegate: class {
    func manageCellDeletePressed(id: Int)
}

class ManageCell {
    var name: UILabel
    var viewBelowButton: UIView
    var deleteButton: UIButton
    weak var delegate: ManageCellDelegate?
    var id: Int
    init (id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,15,250,40))
        self.name.text = name
        self.name.sizeToFit()
        self.viewBelowButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 0, 70, 70))
        //set outside the visible area so that it can be animated in.
        self.viewBelowButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,70,70))
        self.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: "deleteButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.deleteButton.setTitle("delete", forState: .Normal)
    }

    func deleteButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate?.manageCellDeletePressed(id)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cellView: [UIView] = []
    var manageCells: [ManageCell] = []

    func fullManageCells() {
        for id in 0...15 {
            let manageCell = ManageCell(id: id, name: "something")
            manageCell.delegate = self
            manageCells.append(manageCell)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: ManageCellDelegate {
    func manageCellDeletePressed(id: Int) {
        println("button with id \(id) pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an error -  `'ManageCell' does not have a member named 'delegate'` on the line with `self.delegate?.manageCekkDeletePressed(id)` and `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: `ViewController.self` is an instance of the `Class` type. If that were the only problem, there would be an "unrecognized selector" crash. The first problem is that the action is not being triggered at all.

Comment: @an23lm it seems you've missed the `weak var` line from my example

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that. Okay, I included it now and now there are no errors, but still no function call...

Comment: Maybe some bug in Xcode beta. Because, I made an array of buttons in `ViewController` and added them onto the `CellView` in the `ViewController` file and even made sure that all of the button's superview are within the screen's bounds during init. Weirdly, I've another button which I setup using `main.storyboard` which works fine.

Comment: Okay, something is totally wrong with Xcode, I programmatically added a simple button on the main `view` in `viewDidLoad()` and that button doesn't work either. Only buttons added using **storyboard** work... Where as the same code works on a new project. I think my current project files are corrupted.

Comment: @an23lm I'll check it later